# How to list instances that have tag1:<anyvalue> AND tag2:<anyvalue> AND tag3:<anyvalue>

Tags: amazon-web-services, tags, monitoring, terraform, datadog

I need to identify in my infrastructure which hosts have tag1 and tag2 and tag3.
I'm new to datadog but it seems that when filtering I have to specify a value for a specific tag.
I also need to identify the inverse, list hosts that have tag1 but are missing tag2 OR tag3.

I have setup a dashboard for each of the tags, I seem to be limited by up 2 tags.
e.g filter by -> env:dev
    group by -> tag1 , tag2

I would expect to be able to see what hosts have tag1 AND tag2 AND tag3

And the inverse -> what hosts do not have all 3 tags.

Answer (score 0):

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --filters "Name=tag:Department,Values=RnD" --filters "Name=tag:Name,Values=Server1"
```